# What's the most commonly used opposite of "I'm happy for you"?

Tags: expressions

A context:

> I've heard that you won. I'm happy for you.

An opposite context:

> I've heard that you lost. _________________________

To fill in the blank that should have the opposite sense of "I'm happy for you", how about these?

> (1a) I'm sorry for you.
>
> (1b) I feel sorry for you.
>
> (2a) I'm sad for you.
>
> (2b) I feel sad for you.
>
> (3a) I'm bad for you.
>
> (3b) I feel bad for you.

Do these sound idiomatic to native speakers?

Also, I wonder if there's any better alternative(s) for the blank.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54660/discussion-on-question-by-jk2-whats-the-most-commonly-used-opposite-of-im-hap).

Comment: This post now has forty (40) comments, most deleted, but still growing; let’s not further add to that tally. As it is [now under discussion over on our Meta site](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/10078/2085), please contribute to that meta-discussion there rather than arguing further about it in comments here. Thank you.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A common expression is: ***I feel for you***.

***[feel for someone](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/feel-for-someone)***
— phrasal verb 
​

> to experience sympathy for someone:
>   - *I know she’s unhappy, and I feel for her.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: Thank you. I'd say your answer's spot on! Could you also let me know what you think of the examples I have presented? Especially, "(3a) I'm bad for you"?

Comment: "I am bad for you" suggests the idea that you are bad or the other person thinks you are bad. "I feel bad for you" is fine.

Comment: Thanks! So, I think (3a) doesn't work in the given context. Do all the other examples work in the given context?

Comment: Yes, I'd say so.

Comment: @JK2 Josh is right but you need to be aware that they carry widely different nuances. For example, "I feel sorry for you" is perhaps more used in sarcasm. e.g. "You voted Brexit?" - "I feel sorry for you".

Comment: @WS2 I see. But now that you mention sarcasm, I'm beginning to wonder if any of the other examples except for (3a) -- or even "I feel for you" -- can also be used in sarcasm.

Comment: Any expression can be used sarcastically, it depends on context and, especially  in spoken language, by the tone you use. In your sentence, as it stands, it can hardly sound sarcastic.

Comment: @Josh I do agree that any expression can be used sarcastically. But "I feel sorry for you" is quite a heavy sentiment to express, if used other than sarcastically. We rarely say directly to someone "I feel sorry for you" - even if we do. Though we might say of a third party "I feel sorry for George, he's suffered two close bereavements in six months".

Comment: "My commiserations" works very well, although is a little formal.

Comment: @i-CONICA -I think someone has already made that suggestion.

Comment: I suppose it's OK if you feel for me, as long as you don't actually reach me...

Answer (score 38):

I would say "I'm sorry to hear that".

I always have the feeling that if I say "I'm sorry" I'm accepting some kind of responsibility.

Comment: Specifically, "I was sorry to hear that you lost."

Comment: Also, feeling sorry for or pitying a person is offensive to that person.  But it's OK to be sorry about _things_:  "I'm sorry to hear that"; "I'm sorry for your loss"; "I'm so sorry."

Comment: "I'm sorry" is only a sympathetic statement; a recognition that someone has been deprived of something, and nothing more.  I've always wondered by people confuse sympathy for responsibility.  It is one of the things that held Australia back politically for many years after the harm caused by previous generations.  That doesn't mean that it can't be extended to accept responsibility e.g. "I'm sorry that I offended you", but alone it is never so.

Comment: @tudor Because we use the same word when we *do* mean that we are accepting responsibility. “I’m sorry” is not *only* a sympathetic statement; in other contexts, it can be an apology, which is an implicit acceptance of responsibility. Your claim that alone it is never so is flatly incorrect. It’s a problem with the English language. But then, I also suspect that in most political situations where someone (or some country) is expect to say “I’m sorry,” an apology is actually what is desired, not merely sympathy, so even if the English language were less ambiguous it probably wouldn’t help.

Comment: @KRyan If what you say is true, then it would indeed discourage people from showing sympathy.  I feel that adding an overtone of responsibility to a sympathetic word confuses people and negates its value.  In our political case, it was not possible to accept responsibility because they themselves had not made the decision, so a stalemate ensued until new politicians took the responsibility out in order to move forward through sympathy to resolution.  Tying or even implying responsibility in this situation created real issues for tens of thousands of people for many years.

Comment: @tudor it's still a problem for millions to this day. Apologizing for something can actually create legal and financial liability, even though it's ridiculous.

Comment: @barbecue A Japanese friend told me about a leaflet Japanese travellers get from the travel agent when they go abroad. Because Japanese are very polite and apologise for everything all the time, the leaflet tells them "if you are in a car accident, do not say sorry to anyone, because this will be taken as an admission of guilt" and you will get in big trouble.

Answer (score 14):

You can use a single word: *commiserations*.

> **Commiserations** *noun*
>   1.1 commiserations Expressions of sympathy and sorrow for another.
>   ‘To the victors our sincere congratulations, to the vanquished our equally sincere commiserations.’
>   ‘I offer you my commiserations on the situation in which you find yourself.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/commiseration)

For your sample sentence, it would look like this:

- I've heard that you lost. Commiserations.

Comment: Thanks, and I'm sorry, Lawrence. I've changed my examples along with the numbering. Could you please update your answer accordingly?

Comment: I would add that this is a very formal expression, and said vis-a-vis to a distraught player who had lost an important match, would sound somewhat distant and cold.

Comment: @Mari-Lou Although that is cultural. There's a certain subset of stiff-upper lip Britishness it would fit in to perfectly. Possibly to be followed by "Poor show old chap!"

Comment: @JK2 That's ok. I've taken out the references to your set of sentences. To answer the question in the body of your question - I don't think any of the sample sentences are particularly idiomatic. Josh's "I feel for you" is a very good fit for that form. Of your numbered sentences, don't use 3b - that's a statement about your nature or your action, not your sympathy.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, you're right. It's rather too cerebral to be of much comfort in a time of personal difficulty. In the context of cheering up someone who lost a game of sports, though, it's probably fine. :)

Comment: "I offer you my commiserations" is formal, but *commiserat** isn't necessarily formal on its own. If my team lost, we might plan to go eat something and commiserate, or I might ask one of my friends to come over and commiserate with me if I got kicked out of school, etc..

Comment: @MissMonicaE Yes, good point.

Answer (score 5):

There is the idiom ***(that's) too bad***:

> It is unfortunate.; I'm sorry to hear that.
>   *Tom: I hurt my foot on our little hike. Fred: **That's too bad**. Can I get you something for it? Tom: No, I'll live.*
>   *Bob: My uncle just passed away. Tom: **That's too bad**. I'm sorry to hear that. Bob: Thanks.*
>   <sub>[The Free Dictionary by FARLEX](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/too+bad)</sub>

Notice that the second example above also adds *I'm sorry to hear that.* But, the idiom works by itself for your example:

> I've heard that you lost. ***That's too bad.***

Comment: In my experience, "that's too bad" often has a negative or ironic connotation and might not be appropriate.

Comment: All of the provided examples can be used negatively or ironically. *Fred: I've heard that you lost. That sucks. Barney: Thanks. Fred: Sucks to be you!* It does not mean they cannot be used to convey genuine sympathy. I have not experienced an over abundance of ironic uses of *too bad*.

Answer (score 3):

> I've heard that you lost. That sucks.

Not literally the opposite, but the literal opposite ('I'm sad for you') is kind of nonsensical. Commiseration is the appropriate response in this situation.

Comment: Please provide reference to support your answer.

Comment: This would be considered very informal.

Comment: On the other hand, "That sucks" is only a couple of off-ramps down the turnpike from "Sucks to be you," which amounts to saying "I wouldn't want to be in your shoes" and, like that expression, is far more observational than commiserative.

Answer (score 2):

"**How Unfortunate**" is a formal and not-so emotional way to express your feelings.

"**Sorry To Hear That**" Is also quite formal and in the Unites States, it is often shortened to "I'm Sorry" as you may have seen in Hollywood films.

"**My Apologies**" is not a very common saying and mainly used by older and upper-class people

"**My Condolences**" is basically the same as the previous one, both in popularity and syntax.

"**That's A Bummer**" is more colloquial and mainly used in the United States, it wouldn't be used in response to anything serious, like the loss of a family member. You could say "that's a bummer" if someone lost a bet, for example.

Answer (score 2):

On a slightly different track than the other answers, and depending on circumstances, the phrase [better luck next time](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/better-luck-next-time) is one I use frequently.  Obviously this only works in circumstances where there is likely to be a next time...

> *I'm sorry you didn't get a better SAT score, but better luck next time.*

-Cambridge Dictionary online

Answer (score 1):

**Hard luck** (or 'tough luck'). Using your example —

> I heard that you lost. Hard luck!

To me, would sound much more casual than a longer sentence (e.g. "I'm sorry to hear that", etc.) From [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hard-luck):

> **hard luck!** *(British)*
>
> used to express sympathy to someone because something slightly bad has happened:
>
> *"We lost again." "Oh, hard luck!"*

Example in context from the BBC (I think it's a podcast):

> **Callum:** … Well that’s about all we have today, before we go though, the answer to
>   this week’s question. Which planet is mostly closest to Earth? Neil, you
>   said ….
>
> **Neil:** I said Mars.
>
> **Callum:** It’s actually Venus. Venus is actually closest to Earth for most, for most time.
>   **So hard luck on that one.**
>
> — [BBC Learning English 6 Minute English: *Day-trip with a difference*](http://downloads.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/6minute/6minute_080917_day_trip.pdf)

---

'Tough luck' can go both ways — showing sympathy or indifference — so maybe best to use with care. For example, here is Novak Djokovic commiserating with Andy Murray, after beating him in last year's Australian Open:

> I need to pay respect to Andy for having another great tournament. **Tough luck tonight.**
>
> He's a great champion, great friend and a great professional who I'm sure will have many more chances to win this trophy.
>
> — [BBC Newsround: *Novak Djokovic beats Andy Murray to win sixth Australian Open title*](http://www.bbc.co.uk/newsround/35454544)

But the only definition given by [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tough-luck) is the opposite one:

> **tough luck**
>
> (offensive: tough shit; *informal*)
>
> said to show that you have no sympathy for someone's problems or difficulties:
>
> *"They lost a lot of money on their investment." "Tough luck - they should have been more careful."*

Answer (score -1):

I'm *actually* happy for you.

Most times I've heard "I'm happy for you" was either envy/disinterest very rarely shared joy in my experience

Instead,  I would say

> Sorry to hear about your loss

And by saying "to hear about" you emphasise it's a mere event not something  serious.   In this specific context *sorry* is fine as long as you refer to the event as an event not a shared experience.  Except it's a shared experience in which case you can say

> I know how you feel.

Comment: Perhaps this is better as a comment rather than an answer. What would you say to someone who lost an important match? And if you can, please supply an explanation, or some external support for your choice. Otherwise your contribution risks being deleted by the community. Thanks.

Comment: Edited.. was making a quip

Comment: Not my downvote, but "I'm sorry for your loss" is usually said to a bereaved person, not to someone who has lost a match. It's a bit over the top IMO. *I know how you feel* is much better, and I'd place it in **bold** if I were you. EDIT: Ops. "sorry to hear about your loss" is actually better. +1 from me.

Comment: Sorry "about" not for

Comment: Also by saying "to hear about" you emphasise it's a mere event not something as serious as death

Comment: @Josh, I'd disagree that adding "to hear about" makes it sound less serious — I've often heard 'to hear about' used to show that someone didn't tell you something directly: "Sorry to hear about your grandfather passing away". To make it sound less serious, personally, I'd add more context: "Sorry to hear that you lost the cup final last week"